# tkinter canvas: text object variable font size?

Tags: python, text, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making some pretty pictures using a tkinter canvas and overlaying text on top of circles like in the following picture:

http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2012/11/6/1352220546059/Causes-of-deaths-graphic-008.jpg

I want the font size to be dependent on the same number that the circle size is dependent on.

```
tempfont = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica',size=int(round(ms*topnode[1])))
self.display.create_text(center[0],center[1],fill = "#FFFFFF",text = int(round(ms*topnode[1])),font = tempfont)
```

My problem is that when I use the above code, the overlayed text is a constant size for every text object.  The text itself is right, as in it displays the number that I want the font size to be, just not in the correct font size.  I've experimented with putting in constant integers in the size definition (works as it's supposed to), and adding a del(tempfont) immediately after the above 2 lines of code, but I haven't found what fixes this problem yet.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a self-contained little program that reproduces the problem:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

class TestApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, height = 160, width = 400):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.display = Canvas(self, width = 800, height = 320, bg = "#FFFFFF")
        self.display.grid(row=0,column=0)

        def recurtext(tsize):
            if tsize > 20:
                recurtext(tsize-10)
            tempfont = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica',size=tsize)
            self.display.create_text(800 - (tsize*12),160, text = str(tsize), font = tempfont)

        recurtext(60)

app = TestApp()
app.master.title("Test")
app.mainloop()
```

The gist is that `recurtext` resizes the font recursively, and `shows` writes out the font size in that size... or I think it should.  Maybe this is a bug with tkinter, but I'm still holding on to some hope that I'm the one who made a mistake in the logic here.

Comment: Include a self-contained example that reproduces your problem. I just made one and it works just fine here, so I have no idea what is your problem.

Comment: Added.  It looks like it has something to do with the recursion, I think.

Comment: The bug has been reported at http://bugs.python.org/issue802310, but it took too long to get finally patched. You don't need to actually use `tkFont` for that, just pass `font=('Helvetica', tsize)`, for example, when calling `create_text`.

Answer (score 2):

I've never run across this behavior before; it looks like a Tkinter bug. The good news is, there appears to be a workaround. If you give each font a unique name the problem seems to vanish.

The following example shows multiple lines, each with a different font size:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.display = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=600, background="black")
        self.display.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        y = 10
        for size in range (2, 38, 2):
            tempfont = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica',size=size, 
                                   name="font%s" % size)
            self.display.create_text(10, y, fill = "#FFFFFF",text = size, 
                                     font = tempfont, anchor="nw")
            y = y + tempfont.metrics()["linespace"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = Example(parent=root)
    frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For older Python versions, that can only happen if `str(id(self))` is the same for two instances. And I remember it was possible to cause such thing, here is the bug report: http://bugs.python.org/issue802310. Newer versions use a simple counter from 1, so this never happens.

Comment: @mmgp: I'm not entirely sure what point you were trying to make. I was witnessing the problem with python 2.7. By "newer versions" are you speaking of the 3.x series?

Comment: The bug report is more than 9 years old, too bad the patch was applied only for Python 3.3. I'm also pointing out the bug and why it happens (it is in the report), which is known for a long time.